# How to print the lines that contains certain strings by order?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have two files

file `indv`

```
COPDGene_P51515
COPDGene_V67803
COPDGene_Z75868
COPDGene_U48329
COPDGene_R08908
COPDGene_E34944
```

file `data`

```
    COPDGene_Z75868  1   
    COPDGene_A12318  3
    COPDGene_R08908  5
    COPDGene_P51515  8
    COPDGene_U48329  2
    COPDGene_V67803  8
    COPDGene_E34944  2
    COPDGene_D29835  9
```

I want to print the lines that contains the strings in the `indv` by the order of `indv` like following

```
COPDGene_P51515  8
COPDGene_V67803  8
COPDGene_Z75868  1
COPDGene_U48329  2
COPDGene_R08908  5
COPDGene_E34944  2
```

I tried to use

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} ($1 in a)' indv data
```

But I got

```
        COPDGene_Z75868  1   
        COPDGene_R08908  5
        COPDGene_P51515  8
        COPDGene_U48329  2
        COPDGene_V67803  8
        COPDGene_E34944  2
```

which is not the order of `indv`.

Comment: Does the problem has to be solved using a combination of system commands? Assuming the machine has no python etc installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next;} {print a[$1]}' data indv
COPDGene_P51515  8
COPDGene_V67803  8
COPDGene_Z75868  1
COPDGene_U48329  2
COPDGene_R08908  5
COPDGene_E34944  2
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next;}`

  For the first file read, data, save each line in associative array `a` under the index of its first field, `$1`.  Skip the rest of the commands and start over on the `next` line.
- `print a[$1]`

  If we get here, we are working on the second file, indv.  For this file, print each line from data that corresponds to the first field on this line.  In this way, the contents of each line is controlled by data but the order of printing is controlled by indv.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} a[$1]{print $1,a[$1]}' data indv
COPDGene_P51515 8
COPDGene_V67803 8
COPDGene_Z75868 1
COPDGene_U48329 2
COPDGene_R08908 5
COPDGene_E34944 2
```

**Advantages**: Only the second field is stored in memory, instead of the full record from data. It does not try to print a record from indv that does not have a match in data.

**Disadvantages**: It will keep only the last entry from data, if the lines were not unique.